# Dropdown dynamic update list - apps script / javascript / googlesheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, drop-down-menu

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRjue.jpg
Hi,
as a title,
I have on C:C 14 dropdowns menu with F:F list, (see the img link on top)
I create via Apps script

```
actlist = main.getRange('F10:F24')

let dropdownPosition = main.getRange(10,3,15)
dropdownAct = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(actList).build();
dropdownPosition.setDataValidation(dropdownAct) ;
```

I'm a real beginner and my problem that I can't solve is "how to remove/hide from the list the values already used in the previous dropdown, to avoid entering the same value twice

I tried to create two columns and using FILTER AND COUNTIF I was going to remove the values already used, but obviously the dropdown came back to me
"Invalid: Input must fall within specified range"
because the value was no longer included in the list

Is there a quicker system, perhaps in javascript / app script to solve this problem without errors?

Thanks in advance

```
actlist = main.getRange('F10:F24')

let dropdownPosition = main.getRange(10,3,15)
dropdownAct = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(actList).build();
dropdownPosition.setDataValidation(dropdownAct) ;
```

I tried to create two columns and using FILTER AND COUNTIF I was going to remove the values already used, but obviously the dropdown came back to me
"Invalid: Input must fall within specified range"
because the value was no longer included in the list

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link from Google Support from a year ago that may help with how to write the script.  The author has a video tutorial and sample spreadsheet.

I can't think of a way to achieve this without a script or multiple helper columns that continually filter out the previous selections.  Each cell with the dropdown would reference the next subsequent filtered helper column.  Achievable on a sheet with a small number of choices, but impractical otherwise.

https://support.google.com/docs/thread/147199027/3-dependent-dropdown-menus-how-to-avoid-invalid-input-must-fall-within-specified-range?hl=en

At any rate, hope this helps point you in the right direction.